# Strip white-space from HTML before parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a Python dictionary containing HTML that I would later like to parse using `beautifulsoup`, but before parsing I would like to remove white-space directly adjacent to tag elements.

For example:

```
string = "text <tag>some texts</tag> <tag> text</tag> some text"
>>> remove_whitespace(string)
'text<tag>some texts</tag><tag>text</tag>some text'
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What have you tried so far? What is going wrong with it?

Comment: Remove whitespaces from parsed element text. It is much simpler.

Comment: the string is actually a key of a dict, and I want to iterate and parse. How can `strip()` before parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're allowing any kind of tag name, and that tags never contain angle brackets within them, you can quickly solve this with a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "text <tag>some texts</tag> <tag> text</tag> some text"
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\s*(<[^<>]+>)\s*")
>>> regex.sub("\g<1>", string)
'text<tag>some texts</tag><tag>text</tag>some text'
```

**Explanation:**

```
\s*     # Match any number of whitespace characters
(       # Match and capture in group 1:
 <      # - an opening angle bracket
 [^<>]+ # - one or more characters except angle brackets
 >      # - a closing angle bracket
)       # End of group 1 (used to restore the matched text later)
\s*     # Match any number of whitespace characters
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That link has nothing to do with the problem here. The question is about stripping whitespace adjacent to tag "tokens", completely irrespective of tag position.